# Need to run a query that returns data for every hour even if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I tried searching for something similar but couldn't quite pinpoint the problem.

Currently working in Oracle 11g

I have a table, let's call it TEST_DATA, with columns "SITE", "DAY", "TIME" AND "TEMPERATURE", that holds average temperature data for a specific site at a specific day and time, and it will not contain data for every hour of every day. At the moment, let's say I only have this data:

TEST DATA:

[image]

What I need, is to build a view or a query, that returns a set of results for every day and every hour, even if it's not in the TEST_DATA table (returning 0 in that case), which would return a result similar to:

```
SITE | DAY | TIME | TEMPERATURE
Home |   1 |    0 |           0
Home |   1 |    1 |           0
Home |   1 |    2 |           0
Home |   1 |    3 |          15
Home |   1 |    4 |           0
Home |   1 |    5 |          23
Home |   1 |    6 |           0
Home |   1 |    7 |           0
Home |   1 |    8 |           0
Home |   1 |    9 |           0
Home |   1 |   10 |           0
...  | ... |  ... |         ...
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could go about doing this using SQL?

I tried having a table with 24*31 entries and day/time columns, making a row for each day/time pair, but haven't figured out a way to get this working as I want.

I want to try and avoid to make this last table with that many rows for each of the possible sites, since I'm working with over 2000 different sites, which would make the table over a million rows long.

I appreciate any help on the matter.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Gordon Linoff's answer, I was able to adapt to my table and got the results exactly as I wanted them. The query ended up being:

```
SELECT s.SITE, d.DAY, d.TIME, td.TEMPERATURE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SITE FROM TEST_DATA) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM TEST_DAY_TIME) d LEFT JOIN
     TEST_DATA td
ON td.SITE = s.SITE AND td.DAY = d.DAY AND td.TIME = d.TIME 
ORDER BY d.DAY, d.TIME;
```

The other table was something like this, all the way to 31.
[TEST_DAY_TIME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDINZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all the rows and then use `left join` to bring in the values. This is the basic idea:

```
select s.site, d.date, h.time, t.temperature
from (select distinct site from t) s cross join
     (select distinct day from t) d cross join
     (select 0 as time from dual union all select 1 from dual union all . . .
      select 23 from dual) h left join
     t
     on t.site = s.site and t.day = d.date and t.time = h.time;
```

Of course, you will get duplicates if a day/time combination appears multiple times in the original table.

Comment: By using the other table I mentioned, the one with the 744 day/time pairs as the cross join with the first table, I was able to simplify the query a bit and works perfectly. Thanks for the prompt answer, I'll be marking your reply as the answer since I ended up going with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some time data then outer join to your data so you have the basis of the empty times.

This can be done with a simple use of connect by as the following.  This will use 1/1/17 as the start date and give you 1 hour increments for the next 100 days.

```
select to_date('01-jan-17','dd-mon-yy') + numtodsinterval(level,'HOUR') as date_by_hour
    from dual
    connect by level <= 24*100;
```

You then can put your data and this data together via an outer join like the following...

```
WITH time_data as
    (select to_date('01-jan-17','dd-mon-yy') + numtodsinterval(level,'HOUR') as date_by_hour
    from dual
    connect by level <= 24*100),
     test_data(site, day, time, temp) as
    (select 'HOME', 1, 3, 50 from dual union all
     select 'HOME', 1, 4, 51 from dual union all
     select 'HOME', 1, 7, 55 from dual union all
     select 'HOME', 1, 12, 60 from dual)
select NVL(test_data.site,'HOME') as site, time_data.date_by_hour, NVL(test_data.temp,0) as temp 
  from time_data
    left outer join test_data on (time_data.date_by_hour = 
                      to_date('01-jan-17','dd-mon-yy')+numtodsinterval(test_data.day-1,'DAY')+numtodsinterval(test_data.time,'HOUR')
                    AND test_data.site = 'HOME')                      
order by time_data.date_by_hour;
```

Another point, I would suggest that you store your date/time data as a DATE and not simply a number day and number time.

Comment: Thanks. The actual production table is set up as date, I just set up the test one as simple numbers just to quickly try stuff without complicating matters with date functions. But thanks for the advice.